# Preloading pictures for refresh, cache

Tags: php, javascript, html, caching

I have these two php variables: `$img1src` and `$img2src`, (them being PHP is irrelevant as you can echo a php variable anywhere) they both hold a URL of an image. I was wondering if I was able to preload these images, or cache them.

My goal is: when someone ***refreshes*** the page I want these pictures to instantly appear in a `<img src >`.

Comment: This question is acutely suffering from more people on Stack Overflow needing to read [this article.](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching an image isn't really a job for PHP. PHP should be used to decide whether or not to display it. (There are caching things you can do with PHP, but not in the same sense.) Essentially, what you want to do is make the clients browser request the second image. Once the browser gets the image, it should automatically send an "if-modified-by" parameter in the header. Next time you load the page, the response code should be 304 and your image should load instantly. You can choose from a variety of ways to do this. Load the image with javascript after the page has loaded (to prevent additional load time) or you can just include an image tag that is hidden on the page some where.

I also haven't tested it, but you might be able to send an ajax request to the image directly. I'm not sure if that way would cache it or not.

EDIT: 
This isn't the most elegant solution, but it should get the idea across.

JS Example:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['graphic'])) $_SESSION['graphic'] = "http://www.tomsfreelance.com/laptop/DSC_0011.JPG";
else $_SESSION['graphic'] = "http://www.tomsfreelance.com/laptop/DSC_0012.JPG";
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadImage() {
    document.getElementById('preload').style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.tomsfreelance.com/laptop/DSC_0012.JPG)";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadImage();">
<div id="preload" style="display: none;"></div>
<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['graphic'];?>">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example, this sounds exactly like what i want!

Comment: Not the ajax request the loading image with javascript.

Comment: Could u explain exactly what that does?

Comment: it looks to me as if after the body loads it makes the background image of "preload" to be that url. Is preload hidden? and I'm trying to get the image the next time I refresh

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to provide specific code, because I don't want to give you a fish, but rather show how google is a fishing pole.

I googled `"php cache images tutorial"` just to see what would come up. Below is a great resource.

http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/how-to-cache-images-generated-by-php.html

Can't get much better than that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, try this `javascript`:

```
var image1 = new Image(), image2 = new Image();
image1.src = <?php echo $img1src; ?>;
image2.src = ?<php echo $img2src; ?>;
```

That should preload the image so when you append an `img` tag to the `DOM` the image should appear right away.

Comment: Yes but I'm looking to load the pictures, and then view them right away upon refreshing the page

Comment: @AaronBoswell: They will be cached in the browser so if they are meant to show up on a page refresh, they will show up right away (after a `301 not modified` code is sent back)

Comment: javascript vars cache automatically?

Comment: also then would i say <img scr = image1 >

Comment: @AaronBoswell: I think you need to edit your question to be more specific as to what you want to do.

Comment: Just did I hope that makes more sense. Also how do I put a javascript image as the img src?

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to make less http requests overall: you can try [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) and/or [Data Url](http://dataurl.net/#about) methods of displaying these images.  These methods will be the most effective when the images are smaller.

Comment: My aim is to make these images load on the page, and when you refresh it displays the preloaded images instantly. Would CSS Sprites be a legitament way of doing that?

Comment: @Aaron, That's a caching thing. Some clients can choose to have no cache, so you can't force that on everyone.

Comment: Could you please post an example of how I would do that if the client accepted this method?

Comment: Do you not know the answer to what I'm asking or are you just not going to bother writing out an answer for me?

Comment: Aaron, if you're "not going to bother" reading how to do what YOU want to know, then why would I "bother" to spoon feed you? The next time you want to know something, maybe you'll put in some effort of your own BEFORE someone is gracious enough to help you at all.

Comment: I didn't mean to come off as rude, I've been to that page myself before a few times in the last hour or two while trying to figure out cacheing and I don't quite understand it, I came to stack overflow hoping someone would be able to help me comprehend it.

Comment: @jlaceda, sorry for hijacking the comments on your answer. I have added my own answer. I just wanted to add a helpful comment and tool to your answer.